# Do I need Xcode to use Quartz Composer?

Tags: xcode, quartz-composer

Or can I delete Xcode after I've got Quartz Composer? I don't want to keep the app if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can download the Graphic Tools separately and install it where you want (https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#). You don't have to download XCode at all.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can delete Xcode. An easy way to find out is to compress Xcode in the Finder (right click (or control-click) on it, and choose "Compress Xcode.app"), then throw away the app and run Quartz Composer. If it breaks, uncompress Xcode. If it works, you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a standalone application based on Quartz Composer's `QCView` class, you definitely need Xcode. There's also`QCRenderer` class which is designed for low-level rendering of Quartz Composer compositions. This is the class to use if you want to be in charge of rendering a composition to a specific OpenGL context.